# spring MVC multiple files upload

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using spring MVC and JSP. I want to upload 2 files, issue is only one file is getting uploaded. Below is the code:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="/createRequest.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
//form elements like textbox, checkbox
    <tr>
        <th class="RelReqstAllign"></th><td> (Or)<input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="RelReqstAllign"></th><td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" /></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Below is the spring controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response,
        final @ModelAttribute("spRequestDTO") SPRequestDTO dto,
        final BindingResult beException,
        final @RequestParam("buttonName") String buttonName,
        @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws IOException {
    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
        for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload) {

            System.out.println("Saving file: "
                    + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

            if (!aFile.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                try {
                    aFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + aFile.getOriginalFilename()));
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the controller, `fileUpload` is showing only one file, even when I upload two files.

Below is the code added in Spring-mvc.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just do like this. you dont need to have more than `input` tag in your form to select multiple files

```
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" multiple/>
```

It will allow users to select multiple files in their sytem by clicking `ctrl` option in keyboard.

And then, in your action class, do your stuff as you wanted.

Make sure `fileUpload` variable as file array in your bean class

Comment: That means in `@RequestParam("fileUpload[]")CommonsMultiPartFile` ?

Comment: You can use `@RequestParam("fileUpload[]") MultipartFile fileUpload[]`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago and I could not get the handler method handle multiple `MultipartFiles`. As a solution I injected the `HttpServletRequest` and casted it to `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest` to be able to access all files.

```
List<MultipartFile> files = ((DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest) request)
    .getFiles("fileUpload");
```