# Spring upload mutltiple file with one parameter

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to make a little bit complex form for uploading files, 
Since it is different file size, I separate number of type, the form as follows :
[multiple and single file upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLQQI.png)

I have succeeded to upload multi file with different name,

```
<form name="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file.spring?action=upload">
<input type="file" name="upFile[0]">
<input type="file" name="upFile[1]">
<input type="file" name="upFile[2]">
</form>
```

but for the following form

```
<form name="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file.spring?action=upload">
<input type="file" name="upFile">
<input type="file" name="upFile">
<input type="file" name="upFile">
</form>
```

the only file uploaded was the first one,

before inserting, I prepare Util class as follows to get the fileList,

```
public static List<Map<String, MultipartFile>> getFilesFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
        List<Map<String, MultipartFile>> fileList = new ArrayList<Map<String,MultipartFile>>();

        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        Iterator<String> it = multipartRequest.getFileNames();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String key = it.next();
            if(!multipartRequest.getFile(key).isEmpty()){
                Map<String, MultipartFile> file = new HashMap<String, MultipartFile>();
                file.put(key, multipartRequest.getFile(key));           
                fileList.add(file);
            }
        }

        return fileList;
    }
```

is there something that I miss ?

Update :

I found the solution by changing MultipartHttpServletRequest to DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest

Thanks to @Bart , the answer can be found  [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918082/spring-mvc-multiple-files-upload)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same name(upfile) for all the files

```
<form name="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file.spring?action=upload">
<input type="file" name="upFile">
<input type="file" name="upFile">
<input type="file" name="upFile">
</form>
```

and in your Util you are trying to iterate the files by names

```
Iterator<String> it = multipartRequest.getFileNames();
```

So you will get only one

Comment: thank you for your answer @juned-ahsan , do you have any idea how to iterate the list of all value from parameters "upFile" ?

Comment: @tituchio An alternate way to iterate can be to iterate all the parts of request using MultipartHttpServletRequest.getParts() method . You may check the content type of part to decided whether its a file or a form text param.

Comment: Thanks @Juned,  finally I found the solution by changing the request as DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest.