# Uploading multiple files using JSP, Spring with Single Browse button and Single request

Tags: html, spring, jsp, file-upload, multifile-uploader

When I attach two or more files from my front end, in `log.debug` used in the POST method I get only 01 file name and file list size also shows 01.
How can I get all my attached files in my POST method ???

I have my Model class as:

```
//Model
public class MailSenderBean {
    private List<MultipartFile> files;
}
```

JSP View as below with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` :

```
<input name="files" id="filesToUpload" class="button" type="file" multiple/>
```

Controller as:

```
//Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendFiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView sendFiles(@ModelAttribute("mailSenderBean") MailSenderBean mailBean, BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request) {
            User user = AuthManager.getUser( request );

            List<MultipartFile> files = mailBean.getFiles();
            log.debug(" Size ---->>>> "+files.size());

             for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {
                  log.debug("Name ===== >>> "+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename() );
             }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring MVC multiple files upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918082/spring-mvc-multiple-files-upload)

Comment: Not actually. I tried in the same way, but I am not getting correct to-attach file count in POST method. Trying to attach 2 but getting 1.